# Querying for a time period between a time period

Tags: mysql, database, algorithm

I have a PHP page which displays a calendar to users be able to choose a starting period and an ending period matching in what project it will be allocated.

But before I allocate the user in chosen period I need to look up into the database if it’s already allocated.

I have a table which stores allocation data for a resource in some projects. You can see the table and code below.

```
SELECT * FROM ALLOCATION 
WHERE dt_starting >= STR_TO_DATE('2013-09-02', '%Y-%m-%d') 
AND dt_ending <= STR_TO_DATE('2013-09-06', '%Y-%m-%d') 
AND id_res = 1;

id_alloc id_pro id_res  dt_starting dt_ending
----------
1    1  1   2013-09-02  2013-09-06  
2    2  1   2013-09-03  2013-09-04  
----------
```

However when I try to search using a date period from 2013-09-05 to 2013-09-05 or even from 2013-08-31 to 2013-09-03 I receive null in all fields.

Sorry, but I can't put an image here because I don't have many reputation points.

Certainly it's a logic problem but it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

I think your logic is backwards, if you want the constants between the column values:

```
SELECT *
FROM ALLOCATION
WHERE dt_starting <= STR_TO_DATE('2013-09-02', '%Y-%m-%d') AND
      dt_ending >= STR_TO_DATE('2013-09-06', '%Y-%m-%d') AND
      id_res = 1;
```

EDIT:

If you are looking for an overlap between the time periods, then the logic is that one starts before the other ends, and the first ends after the second neds:

```
SELECT *
FROM ALLOCATION
WHERE dt_starting <= STR_TO_DATE('2013-09-06', '%Y-%m-%d') AND
      dt_ending >= STR_TO_DATE('2013-09-02', '%Y-%m-%d') AND
      id_res = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but didn't solve yet, I mean, if I search using the query below nothing is returned.

`SELECT *
FROM ALLOCATION
WHERE dt_starting <= STR_TO_DATE('2013-08-31', '%Y-%m-%d') AND
      dt_ending >= STR_TO_DATE('2013-09-06', '%Y-%m-%d') AND
      id_res = 1;`

Comment: Didn't work man, I've got also one line from '2013-09-01' to '2013-09-10' which isn't in that period.

Comment: @KleberSilva . . . Please edit your question to clarify what you mean by "a time period between time period".  Give examples both of things are meet the condition and things that don't.

Comment: I guess now it's better explained. If not just ask me again. Thank you so far.

Comment: I've tried with the query bellow but still doesn't work.

`SELECT
    *
FROM
    allocation
WHERE
    (dt_starting BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2013/09/09', '%Y/%m/%d') AND STR_TO_DATE('2013/09/11', '%Y/%m/%d'))
    AND
    (dt_ending BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2013/09/09', '%Y/%m/%d') AND STR_TO_DATE('2013/09/11', '%Y/%m/%d'))
    AND id_res = 1;`

Comment: @KleberSilva . . . That's nice.  Did you try it with my recommended answer?

Comment: I've given up from that kind of period intersection. Now I'm thinking in convert both dates to seconds. It'll be more interesting to work with seconds than dates. I guess so. If you have any objection about this, please let me know.